# How to push certain value to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to push all 0.0 value in object, so I can count how many 0.0 value in an object. So far I've made a code to push all values (including 0.0) but now I just want to push **ONLY 0.0 VALUE**. 
for example: 
in `['cm_per1']` there is 2 "0.0", then I want to push them as `final_results['ESL']['cm_per1']` and when I call `final_results['ESL']['cm_per1'].length`, it will show "**2**" (because there is 2 "0.0" in  `cm_per1`)

here is what I've made so far >> http://jsfiddle.net/xKJn8/26/

```
var data = {
  "MyData": [
    {
      "cm_per1": "21.9",
      "cm_per2": "31.8",
      "tipe": "ESL"
    },
    {      
      "cm_per1": "8.6",
      "cm_per2": "7.0",
      "tipe": "ESL"
    },
    {      
      "cm_per1": "3.2",
      "cm_per2": "0.0",
      "tipe": "ESL"
    },
    {
      "cm_per1": "0.0",
      "cm_per2": "0.0",
      "tipe": "ESL"
    },
    {
      "cm_per1": "0.0",
      "cm_per2": "0.0",
      "tipe": "ESL"
    }
  ]
};

var final_results = {},
    type,
    current_row= "";
for (var i=0; i<data.MyData.length; i++) {
    current_row = data.MyData[i];
    type = current_row.tipe;

    //I want to count how many cm_per1 and cm_per2 that have 0.0 value    
    if (!final_results[type]) {
            final_results[type] = {
                  "cm_per1": [],
                  "cm_per2": []  
            };
    }

    final_results[type].cm_per2.push(current_row.cm_per2);
    final_results[type].cm_per1.push(current_row.cm_per1);
}
//but the result is it counts all cm_per1 and cm_per2, and what I need is only counts that have 0.0 value
console.log(final_results['ESL']['cm_per1'].length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var final_results = {};

data.MyData.forEach( function( o ) {
    // First check if it doesn't exist :-)
    if (!final_results[ o.tipe ]) {
        final_results[ o.tipe ] = {
            "cm_per1": [],
            "cm_per2": []  
        };
    }

    // Only push if the value is '0.0'
    if ( o.cm_per1 === '0.0' ) {
        final_results[ o.tipe ][ 'cm_per1' ].push( o.cm_per1 );
    }
    if ( o.cm_per2 === '0.0' ) {
        final_results[ o.tipe ][ 'cm_per2' ].push( o.cm_per2 );
    }
});
console.log( final_results[ 'ESL' ][ 'cm_per1' ].length ); // 2
```

Comment: Oh, guess I misunderstood the question

Comment: thank you for the answer :) but..
yes, I want to get 2 for cm_per1 and 3 for cm_per2, then I want it as array too so I can call them as length. because the value will be dynamically. your first answer is close enough to get what I need, I just put 2 variables (count_1 and count_2) but the problem is I need it as array..that's what makes me confuse

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to change these two lines:

```
final_results[type].cm_per2.push(current_row.cm_per2);
final_results[type].cm_per1.push(current_row.cm_per1);
```

to:

```
if (current_row.cm_per2 === '0.0') {
    final_results[type].cm_per2.push(current_row.cm_per2);
}
if (current_row.cm_per1 === '0.0') {
    final_results[type].cm_per1.push(current_row.cm_per1);
}
```